# Jest: functional component array list not mapping after adding element

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to list person by clicking  onClick function to add empty object so that map can loop
over and show div. I see prop onclick function calling works but i map is not looping over it.

a little help would be appreciated.

```
// functional component

    const listing = ({list=[]}) => (
    <>
        {
        <div id='addPerson'  onClick={() => list.push({})}>Add person</div>}

        {list.map((element, index) => (
        <div key={index} className='listItems'>
            <p>list name</p>            
        </div>
        ))}
    </>
    );

    export default listing;

// test case

it('renders list-items', () => {
 const wrapper = shallow(<listing />);
 wrapper.find('#addPerson').prop('onClick')();
 console.log(wrapper.find('.listItems').length); // showing zero, expected 1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating List is not going to cause a re-render in your component. I am not sure where List is coming from, but I am assuming it is coming from a local state in the parent, or probably redux store. From inside your component, you will have to call a function in your parent to update the list array there.

Below is a version of your component, assuming the list in your local state. You will have to adjust the code to update the state in the parent or redux store, but the below should be enough to give you an idea of what to do. Also, don't push the element to array, as it mutates the object and will not contact re-render.

```
const Listing = ({list = [], addToList}) => {
  return <>
    {
      <div id='addPerson' onClick={() => addToList({})}>Add person</div>}

    {list.map((element, index) => (
      <div key={index} className='listItems'>
        <p>list name</p>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
};
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, your assumptions are right . Here we are using earlier version of react ,  Is it possible to rerender in functional component without using hooks ?

Comment: You don't need to have the state in the same component, this was just for demonstration purposes only. The exact solution will depend on your application. The point I was trying to make is that you will have to update the list in state (wherever it is), instead of updating the list you were getting as prop.

Comment: I have updated my example code to give you a bit more help.

Comment: Thanks I got your point, As there is not re-render for functional component. Thank you for hint.